# "Enter a character to quit" program in C

Tags: c

I try to write a program in C using the loop that repeated until a specific character is inputted from the keyboard. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
    char option;
    do
        {
            printf("Enter q to quit: ");
            option = getchar ();
        }
    while (option != 'q');
}
```

I've also tried with the scanf () but the result always the same. Here the output after I tried to test the program:

```
Enter q to quit: 3
Enter q to quit: Enter q to quit: 2
Enter q to quit: Enter q to quit: 1
Enter q to quit: Enter q to quit: q
```

Can anyone explain to me why the "Enter q to quit : " always appear twice and how can I fix it?

Comment: you don't happen to do "<key><ENTER>"?

Comment: Also, `getchar` returns an `int`, not  a `char`, but that 's more or less a finesse, here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: 1. Add `#include <conio.h>`. 2. Call `_getch` instead of `getchar`. 3. Add `printf("\n");` after calling `_getch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get it printed twice because when you hit enter, a line feed character `\n` is appended to stdin.

You can discard that line feed character by adding an extra getchar:

```
do
{
    printf("Enter q to quit: ");
    option = getchar();
    getchar(); // discard line feed
}while (option != 'q');
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. It assumes there **is** a line feed, and that it is **exactly one byte** long.
It wont work if the user enter only the character (using ^D on linux, for example), or if he uses a windows new line (CRLF).

Comment: @4rzael Sometimes you have to adapt answers to the person asking. The intention is to help a beginner to fix their issue and then move on. It is indeed not 100% portable production level code...

Comment: Sure, but I think using a scanf or just a while skipping all \n ad \r isn't too complicated and get better results

Comment: @4rzael: Windows CRLF is converted to a single \n character by the stdio library, so that particular thing is not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

"Enter q to quit: " appears twice because your input buffer still has the new line character in it when it runs a second time.

Fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    char option;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter q to quit: ");
        option = getchar ();
        while(getchar() != '\n'); //Enter this line here.
    }
    while (option != 'q');
}
```

Comment: `main` prototype, at least, `int main()`

Answer (score 3):

When you enter q, you press q followed by enter (a new line character as far as C is concerned which is \n).

So when your loop returns to the beginning, '\n' is still in your input buffer and getch() automatically reads this and checks whether that equals q before returning to the beginning of your loop again (hence your text looks like it's printed twice).

Try using fgets like this:
`fgets (option , 4 , stdin)`

You have to make sure you have a character array big enough to hold this though so you should define
`char option [3];` to hold 'q', the newline character '\n' and the termination character '\0';

fgets is quite a nice solution because it will only store up the the second argument worth of characters and throw away the rest. This means 1) you don't overflow your variables/arrays and 2) you don't have junk left in the input buffer :)

Comment: You are correct. Thank you, I'll edit this to reflect this. char option[2] works though no? [0] = 'q' and [1] = '\0'. There is no need for a third element in the array.

Comment: Right! Fair enough. Thanks for clearing that up. C adds far too many characters haha ;).

Answer (score 1):

If you hit two keys, you'll read two characters. If you want to read *characters*, call `getchar`. If you want to read *lines*, call some function that reads lines.

Answer (score 0):

getchar() function first reads from the buffer.If buffer is empty then and then it will read from standard input(i.e.screen).